# How to attach an event at runtime to all html elements of a certain type using css?

Tags: javascript, css, events, runtime

Is it possible to attach an event to an html tag with css:

```
input [type="text"]
{
onkeypress (dojob(this));

}
```

Comment: css is used for styling, in short you can't do it with css.

Comment: add :focus so you would put input[type="text"]:focus and it should do it whenever this has focus on it.

Comment: Jose, you can do things to css to directly interact with different layouts, for instance hover. I just answered a question earlier on how to add a box if a input field was checked. It can be done you have to be creative though.

Comment: See this jsfiddle on how css can make changes, http://jsfiddle.net/EgWuy/

Comment: Now, what do you want it to do, though, if you want to process a function or do something you will need javascript, but if it is as simple as show this, or change a background thats different.

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery you may write like this

```
$('input[type=text]').keypress(function() {...})
```

Comment: how much overhead it take?

Comment: Note that this is Javascript, not CSS, as I detailed in my answer. Anwyway, the overhead is very low to unsignificant in modern browser.

Comment: The browser has to process the CSS selector, and attach the handlers to selected elements. Even you can write a CSS as you asked, this two parts must be inevitable. The extra overhead introduced by jQuery should be small enough.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. You could do it with javascript as follows...

```
$('input[type=text]').on("keypress", function() {

});
```

Comment: That's jQuery and Javascript, not CSS!

Comment: Agreed..I have modify my answer.

Comment: Actually, the answer is yes and no: see below ;)

Answer (score 0):

No. At least, it's not standard. If you want a cross-browser solution, then use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) with Javascript.

Anyway, in IE you can reach this by using `.htc` scripts bound to the `behaviour` property, but **don't do that**. In Firefox you can use `-moz-binding` property, which is not standard either.

Comment: can you provide some links to -moz-binding and .htc scripts?

Comment: Sure: [here is a DHTML beahviour (.htc) tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531079(v=VS.85).aspx), [here is the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531078(v=vs.85).aspx). About `-moz-binding`, there is no more reference as I suppose it was removed from the standard and buried in a shallow grave, hoping nobody would regret it. Only found a mention on [Google Caja wiki](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/CssAllowsArbitraryCodeExecution). I'm feeling guilty at letting other people know things that should have been removed from the human knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need to use javascript, but you can use jQuery to select the element using the css selector, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function (e) {
        alert(e.which);
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RYsr8/